# net.sf.json.JSONObject adds backslashes where it's not expected?

Tags: java, json, backslash

I'm loosing my hair trying to figure out why net.sf.json.JSONObject add extra backslash where it shouldn't on my java code :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject ();
obj.element ("column_name", "<a href=\"#\" title=\"test\">Test !</a>");
```

will output :

```
<a href=\"#\" title=\"test\">Test !<\/a>
```

with an extra "\" near </a>.

How can I avoid this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably uses the same method to escape strings in JSON as it does JavaScript strings used in script blocks (`<script ...> ... </script>`) which according to HTML syntax rules may not include the character sequence `</`.

Does this make any difference to you? Escaping "random" characters doesn't change the meaning of a string literals in JSON or JavaScript. The string literals `"/"` and `"\/"` are technically absolutely identical:

```
if ("/" === "\/") alert("The same!");
```

EDIT: BTW, the JSON grammer explicitly lists the forward slash (solidus) as an character that can be escaped.

Comment: Well, that's odd, because I checked what you said and of course, you're right, but the problem is I add the html values in the dom into a table like element from extjs (grid).
The column are broken (the data elements are not well verticaly aligned with the headers) and I found that the problem was coming from an invalid html. I checked the html returned by the request, and except the "\/", everything else is fine.

It's very strange :p

But thanks for your help, I appreciate !

Comment: You would need to give more details then, because right now I can't imagine why escaping the slashes would make problems, but escaping the quotes wouldn't.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but it was with a folder structure, so /folder_name became \/folder_name (I am using org.json) but our parser (cjson) was leaving the backslash in after decoding it to a string.  I used the @ktbiz approach below but on the client side to just replace \/ with / on the JSON string before sending it out.  I read somewhere else that this is a bug in the org.json toString() code, but it sounds more like a bug in the other JSON parsers (cjson in my case) if the JSON schemata approves.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue. Turns out the problem was that my code used both org.json.JSONObject and com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject. The conversion between the two was creating strings and escape characters. Considering you're using net.sf.json.JSONObject, this might be your issue as well. Check your imports for other versions of JSONObject.